# how to Print two column layout in landscape size

Tags: html, css

**I used Bootstrap Framework.**

HTML page designs for **Print question papers**. this layout print **Two column** or **single column layout**.

I used below css:

```
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-count: 2;
 column-count: 2;
```

At media print queries,

```
@page {
 size: A4 landscape ;
 margin-top:0in;
 margin-bottom:0in;
 margin-left:0in;
 margin-right:0in;  
}
```

**This is my html page.**
[image]

**If i print above html page OUTPUT is ,**

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Patel The question is in the title : how to Print two column layout in landscape size